# Confusion related to effective population size

Tags: phylogeny, phylogenetics

I am making a demographic model for African American population in which I say 80% of ancestry comes from African population and 20% comes from European population. I am using the time/population time from [Gazave et al. (2014)](https://www.pnas.org/content/111/2/757).

The authors doe not mention the effective population size (Ne) of African American population after admixture. Is there a publication someone can point me to that mentions the effective population size of African American (AA) or even European American (EA). I know there is not much difference between the two. It's just I need a figure to have my simulation up and running.

**Note** *N*e is an estimate of the people size based genetic diversity and migration and is associated with the Fst statistics

Comment: I am a bit confused about what are you actually up to. I suppose that the admixture of African American and European Americal populations is a continuous process, what do you mean by effective population size after admixture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a fantastic question and in my opinion a really important question in context. The Ne of Africa will be much bigger than the European population, however I'm less sure about the West African population which gave rise to the Afro-American population. I suspect it is still large because of the "out of Africa" theory.

My advice is to start by taking a complete look at the entire subject, from [Tenesa et al (2007)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1832099/pdf/520.pdf).  Ne is a really important parameter in any population study and extremely useful. I have feeling this could be complex, but I cannot hypotheses any further because I don't do human genetics (except for immunology).

Comment: Thank you Micheal for your answer.